# How to create Short URL in Mediawiki without getting an 403 Forbidden Error in Apache?

Tags: htaccess, apache2, mediawiki

> How to create Short URL in Mediawiki without getting an 403 Forbidden Error in Apache?

My **httpd.conf**:

```
#### Wikibase (BETA)
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerName wikibase.isc
        ServerAlias wikibase.isc
        ServerAdmin SuriyaaKudoIsc@users.noreply.github.com
        DocumentRoot "C:/Server/Apache24/htdocs/inc.isc/farm/mediawiki/wikibase"
</VirtualHost>
```

> My MediaWiki's local project name is "wikibase" (with a local dns adress: http://wikibase.isc/).

I use following code for the **LocalSettings.php** file (located in `C:\Server\Apache24\htdocs\inc.isc\farm\mediawiki\wikibase\w`):

```
$wgScriptPath = "/w";
$wgServer = "http://wikibase.isc";
$wgScriptExtension = ".php";
$wgArticlePath = "/wiki/$1";
$wgUsePathInfo = true;
```

I also create an **.htaccess** file in `C:\Server\Apache24\htdocs\inc.isc\farm\mediawiki\wikibase`:

```
## http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache

# Enable the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# Short url for wiki pages
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]

# Redirect / to Main Page
RewriteRule ^/*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
```

---

I get an **403 Forbidden Error** in my Firefox Browser from my local Apache Server 2.4:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /C:/Server/Apache24/htdocs/inc.isc/farm/mediawiki/wikibase/w/index.php on this server.
```

---

**EDIT:**

My new ***httpd.conf*** code:

```
#### Wikibase (BETA)
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerName wikibase.isc
        ServerAlias wikibase.isc
        ServerAdmin SuriyaaKudoIsc@users.noreply.github.com
        DocumentRoot "C:/Server/Apache24/htdocs/inc.isc/farm/mediawiki/wikibase"
</VirtualHost>
<Directory "C:/Server/Apache24/htdocs/inc.isc/farm/mediawiki/wikibase/wiki/">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

My Apache ***server.log*** file:

```
[Sun Jan 10 14:40:47.547054 2016] [core:error] [pid 6260:tid 1052] (20023)The given path was above the root path: [client 127.0.0.1:8634] AH00127: Cannot map GET / HTTP/1.1 to file
[Sun Jan 10 14:40:49.665828 2016] [core:error] [pid 6260:tid 1052] (20023)The given path was above the root path: [client 127.0.0.1:8634] AH00127: Cannot map GET / HTTP/1.1 to file
[Sun Jan 10 14:40:51.601607 2016] [core:error] [pid 6260:tid 1052] (20023)The given path was above the root path: [client 127.0.0.1:8634] AH00127: Cannot map GET / HTTP/1.1 to file
```

My Apache ***access.log*** file:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jan/2016:14:40:49 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 381
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jan/2016:14:40:49 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 381 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jan/2016:14:40:51 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 381
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jan/2016:14:40:51 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 381 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
```

---

### Other resources

These resources were not helpful:

- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457590/how-to-create-short-url-in-mediawiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!

It's important to use **`Alias`** and **`Require all granted`** in ***httpd.conf***!

---

- The **httpd.conf** file:

> This is the configuration of the Apache Sever 2.4!

```
#### Wikibase (BETA)
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerName wikibase.isc
        ServerAlias wikibase.isc
        ServerAdmin SuriyaaKudoIsc@users.noreply.github.com
        DocumentRoot "C:/Server/Apache24/htdocs/inc.isc/farm/mediawiki/wikibase/w/"
        Alias /wiki                     C:/Server/Apache24/htdocs/inc.isc/farm/mediawiki/wikibase/w/index.php
        Alias /wiki/index.php           C:/Server/Apache24/htdocs/inc.isc/farm/mediawiki/wikibase/w/index.php
        Alias /wiki/load.php            C:/Server/Apache24/htdocs/inc.isc/farm/mediawiki/wikibase/w/load.php
        Alias /wiki/api.php             C:/Server/Apache24/htdocs/inc.isc/farm/mediawiki/wikibase/w/api.php
        Alias /wiki/opensearch_desc.php C:/Server/Apache24/htdocs/inc.isc/farm/mediawiki/wikibase/w/opensearch_desc.php
        Alias /wiki/skins               C:/Server/Apache24/htdocs/inc.isc/farm/mediawiki/wikibase/w/skins
        Alias /wiki/images              C:/Server/Apache24/htdocs/inc.isc/farm/mediawiki/wikibase/w/images
</VirtualHost>
Include "conf/wikibase-htaccess.conf"
```

---

- The **LocalSettings.php** file:

> This is the wiki setting file!

```
$wgScriptExtension = ".php";
$wgScriptPath = "/w";
$wgArticlePath = "/wiki/$1";
$wgUsePathInfo = true;
```

---

- The **wikibase-htaccess.conf** file:

> This file is included in httpd.conf!

```
# MediaWiki & Stackoverflow
#<Directory "C:/Server/Apache24/htdocs/inc.isc/farm/mediawiki/wikibase/w/">
#    Options None
#    AllowOverride None
#    Order allow,deny
#    Allow from all
#    SSLRequireSSL
#    SSLRequire  %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}  =~ m/.*serialNumber=<personnummer>$/
#</Directory>
<Directory "C:/Server/Apache24/htdocs/inc.isc/farm/mediawiki/wikibase/w/">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Source: https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Apache/htaccess_configuration
<Directory "C:/Server/Apache24/htdocs/inc.isc/farm/mediawiki/wikibase/w/cache">
  Deny from all
</Directory>
<Directory "C:/Server/Apache24/htdocs/inc.isc/farm/mediawiki/wikibase/w/images">
  # Protect against bug 28235
  <IfModule rewrite_module>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.[^\\/:*?\x22<>|%]+(#|\?|$) [nocase]
    RewriteRule . - [forbidden]
  </IfModule>
</Directory>
<Directory "C:/Server/Apache24/htdocs/inc.isc/farm/mediawiki/wikibase/w/includes">
  Deny from all
</Directory>
<Directory "C:/Server/Apache24/htdocs/inc.isc/farm/mediawiki/wikibase/w/languages">
  Deny from all
</Directory>
<Directory "C:/Server/Apache24/htdocs/inc.isc/farm/mediawiki/wikibase/w/maintenance">
  Deny from all
</Directory>
<Directory "C:/Server/Apache24/htdocs/inc.isc/farm/mediawiki/wikibase/w/maintenance/archives">
  Deny from all
</Directory>
<Directory "C:/Server/Apache24/htdocs/inc.isc/farm/mediawiki/wikibase/w/serialized">
  Deny from all
</Directory>
```

---

- The **.htaccess** file:

> In the .htaccess file there are two possible working methods!

```
###################### 1st Method (currently used) #########################

## http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache

# Enable the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# Short url for wiki pages
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]

# Redirect / to Main Page
RewriteRule ^/*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]


###################### 2nd Method (deactivated) #########################

# Enable the rewrite engine
##RewriteEngine On
##RewriteBase /wiki

# Redirect index.php to non index.php
##RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /(.*)index\.php
##RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

# Internally rewrite request to index.php
##RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
##RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
##RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you encounter a 403 forbidden error it usually is a problem with directory permissions rather than with .htaccess files and rewrite rules.

The first step is to check your servers error log.   The error log often has more information in it than is presented to the user's web browser.

The other thing to try is to check the directory permissions.   Make sure that the user Apache is running as has permissions to read and execute *index.php* in that directory.

Comment: I tried.

1. I checked the log files of my Apache server. (See my updated post!)
2. I tired to check the directory permissions in httpd.conf file.
3. Where is the problem with my directory permissions in httpd.conf file?

Comment: "Given path above the root path" is the crux of your problem.  Google that for solutions.

Comment: I solved it with **`Require all granted`** in *httpd.conf* but now I get an **`Not Found. The requested URL /wiki/Main_Page was not found on this server.`** ***error***. :-/

Comment: Solved it! I put **`Alias /wiki C:/Server/Apache24/htdocs/inc.isc/farm/mediawiki/wikibase/w/index.php`** into *.htaccess* but I must put this in *httpd.conf* file!

Comment: You could submit that as an answer and accept it which would take this question off our "unanswered" list.  (Never mind, I see you already did!)